# JS - Combining the SheetJS library with ExcelJS to be able to styling cells

Tags: javascript, excel, exceljs, sheetjs

I want to be able to style cells. In SheetJS it's possible to use this only in the pro version. This can be implemented in ExcelJS. When using JSON objects and generating a.xlsx file based on data from a page, am I able to transfer values and change the color of cells using ExcelJS (or something else)?

Answer (score 2):

### 1. use fork: `xlsx-styles`

This is a community version of sheetjs that provide styles.

(Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-styles)

### 2. use `sheetjs` + `xlsx-renderer`

1. parse data from a page by using sheetjs
2. pipe data into xlsx-renderer

xlsx-renderer give you a possibility to style a template file inside Windows Excel, so any changes in template are quick and easy.

(Source: https://github.com/Siemienik/xlsx-renderer)